# Python xlwt Formula Parse Error

Tags: xlwt

I am running into a parse error while using xlwt. Simple formula's like SUM() work fine but I tried to run this slight more complex formula and received the following error.

```
xlwt.ExcelFormulaParser.FormulaParseException: can't parse formula =COUNTIFS(hospital_data!C1:C6500,LEFT(B1,4),hospital_data!D1:D65000,RIGHT(B1,1),hospital_data!F1:F65000,A3)
```

This is the code I am attempting to run.

```
hospital_count_formula = '=COUNTIFS(hospital_data!C1:C6500,LEFT({0},4),hospital_data!D1:D65000,RIGHT({0},1),hospital_data!F1:F65000,{1})'.format(quarter_ref, state_ref)

sheet_overview.write(row, column, Formula(hospital_count_formula))
```

I have tried using a defined numerical range (A1:A5000) instead of (A:A) and I have also tried simply passing this through as a string but it is not evaluated in Excel.

This formula does work when copy and pasted into Excel. Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you read the answer that you got when you asked the same question on the python-excel google-group?

(1) Lose the `=` ... compare with your `SUM()` results.

(2) The XLS format doesn't support the `COUNTIFS` function, which was introduced in Excel 2007.

> This formula does work when copy and pasted into Excel.

No, the formula preceded by a `=` so the Excel knows you mean formula instead of text does work,  with Excel **2007 or later** and you didn't try to Save As Excel 97-2003 Workbook (*.xls), which doesn't work.